# how to compile a python script (proxy.cgi) in ubuntu?

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, proxy

I want to know please how to compile a python script ubuntu 14.10, I have a file proxy.cgi I want to compile in order to access to the geoserver. when I type localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi, it displays just the code of proxy.cgi without compiling.

Comment: You don't have to compile python files. In your case I guess you did not setup your Apache properly to execute the script as CGI. Which BTW is not the best way to run a python script on a webserver.

Comment: I have python  in my pc and I placed the proxy.cgi file in / usr / lib / cgi-bin as I found on the internet. when I type localhost/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi, it displays just the code of proxy.cgi without compiling. I want it to compile because otherwise I can not view wfs.

Comment: As Klaus D pointed out, you need to configure apache to enable cgi; please post your apache configurations if you think you have done this.